# WAMP : start mysql through PHP and Batch file

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

How to start mysql server through PHP code by calling the Batch file in exec() or popen() ?

I'm using wampserver 3 64bit.

Comment: Try `exec("NET START wampmysqld");`

Comment: It is working fine. My mysqld name is wampmysqld64. Please post as answer. I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: You can answer your own question. @doe

Comment: @paskl Yes but Matt will get some reputation. :-)

Comment: Done :). Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## For WAMPSERVER

To start:

```
exec("NET START wampmysqld64");
```

To stop:

```
exec("NET STOP wampmysqld64");
```

Comment: I think if he is using WAMPServer 64bit the 2 services are actually called `wampmysqld64` and `wampapache64`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep, I'll change that to suit :)